# Jenkins installed on aws unable to launch on browser

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services

I have a fresh aws instance with Ubuntu 14 installed.

I am trying to install and run jenkins on it. I did the following steps.

Installed java8

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

After that I checked the status of the Jenkins server

```
sudo service jenkins status
```

The response was:

```
Jenkins Automation Server is running with the pid 8355

sudo netstat -ntulp | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      8356/java
```

However, when I go to ipaddress of `<aws_instance_ip_address>:8080` the page does not load.

Going to `<aws_instance_ip_address>` opens the Ubuntu Apache default page.

What do I need to do for Jenkins to launch from browser?

Comment: Are you navigating to the correct AWS ec2 url (http://ec2-[IP].compute-1.amazonaws.com/)? Are your security groups configured correctly?

Comment: Is your host firewall open on port 8080?

Comment: do you get a response from jenkins if you `curl localhost:8080` on the jenkins host? what about `curl <aws_instance_ip_address>:8080` on the jenkins host?

Answer (score 10):

It seems your have not opened your 8080 port in Security Groups in AWS.

Steps:

1. Go to AWS console
2. Click `Security Group` and select the security group that you have assigned to your EC2 instance.
3. Click `Edit Inbound Rules`
4. Add a `Custom TCP Rule` and add `8080` in the `Port Range`.
5. You will now see Jenkins rise from the grave :) i.e. first time installation screen.

P.S.:
My Friend, if you have reached till Step 5, you know what to do next ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had reposted this question in stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339167/jenkins-installed-on-aws-unable-to-launch-on-browser

The answer in comment "open the port 8080 in Ec2 security groups" resolved the issue for me.

Comment: It says page not found!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this post might help you with your question.
[Windows Azure Virtual Machine - Opening a port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117613/17344596) **This is for windows**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/10972)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your have not opened your 8080 port in Security Groups in AWS.

Steps:

Go to AWS console

Click ***Security Group*** and select the security group that you have assigned to your EC2 instance.

Click Edit ***Inbound Rules***

Add a ***Custom TCP Rule*** and add ***8080*** in the Port Range.

You will now see Jenkins first time installation screen.